# D3.js: Trigger an event in a different chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js

I have two identical charts. The graphics for them are built like so:

```
circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 0)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return fill_color; })
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "circle_" + d.id; })
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) { build_tooltip(d, i, this); })
  .on("mouseout", function(d, i) { hide_tooltip(d, i, this); });
```

On `mouseover`, it triggers the following function:

```
build_tooltip = function(data, i, element) {
  var content = "Title: " + data.title;
  show_tooltip(content, d3.event);
}
```

My question is: How can I make it so mousing over a circle in Chart #1 triggers the same mouseover event in Chart #2, but with unique data for each chart?  Chart #2 must generate its own set of data (in this example, just a title). So, how can I make Chart #2's mouseover event fire whenever Chart #1's does?

In jQuery, this would be quite simple -- there is a literal `.trigger()` event. But how can I go about accomplishing the same with D3?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the event with JQuery?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Of course. But how do you feed the data (d, i, this) from Chart #2 to the Chart #2's version of build_tooltip when hovering over a Chart #1 element?  It's the same issue with jQuery.  I need to somehow trigger D3's mouseover event, as far as I can tell, and I have no idea how to do that with either D3 or jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried using D3's [dispatch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch)?
If not, see through this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848) for more details on how to use it.

Comment: @1cgonza Post that as an answer. It's the solution I went with so you should get credit. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, thanks :) would be great if you post a snippet of your working code for others to get a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using D3's [dispatch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch)? If not, see through [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848) for more details on how to use it.